# Accessing Post html from Ghost Blog Custom Handlebars Helper

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, handlebars.js, ghost-blog

Ghost Blog has limited functionality when it comes to outputting content to a post and it's typically done through the {{content}} helper. I am trying to add more nuanced capabilities to the content helper by creating my own handlebars helpers to output blocks of content from within the ghost {{content}} helper.

I've been making use of these two resources to create my own solutions to the problem https://www.neoito.com/ghost-cms-on-steroids-with-custom-block-helpers/
https://github.com/TryGhost/Ghost/wiki/Apps-Getting-Started-for-Ghost-Devs

Everything works fine for the most part, but I've hit a snag when trying to port html from the post {{content}} to the handlebars helper I've registered. I managed to make an ajax call using jquery from the back-end by npm installing it within the registered helper folder. The folder is set up via the method described in the second link (creating an App within the ghost content folder).

in the index file, the helper is stored in a separate function and called when the app activates. My problem is getting the helper function to accept the ajax call and extract the html from the returned value.

I'm not set on this method and there is a way that it has been done in the first link (however, it was created to solve the problem with an older versions of ghost - pre 1.0 and I'm making use of Ghost 1.2.0 so I'm aware of some "breaking changes" have been made).

I need a way to extract the post html from the server side of things (if its even possible). The internal api does not work for me unless it is called inside the activate function but I cant seem to get it to work in the helper function which is outside of the activate functions scope... I'd love some help on this.

Here my index file to give some context to this. If you need any more information, let me know and I'll post (right now I cant think of anything else you might need)

```
const $ = require('jquery');

var App = require('ghost-app'),
    hbs = require('express-hbs'),
    ghost_api = require('ghost/core/server/public/ghost-sdk'),
    proxy = require('ghost/core/server/helpers/proxy'),

helpers_briefcase;

helpers_briefcase = App.extend({

// content: function () {$.get(ghost.url.api('posts', {formats:["html"]})).done(function (data){
//     console.log('posts', data.posts["html"]);
//     return ('posts', data.posts["html"])
//     console.log('it worked');
//     debug('it worked');
//     }).fail(function (err){
//     console.log(err);
//     });
// },

//Filter handling
filters: {
   ghost_head: 'handleGhostHead',
   ghost_foot: 'handleGhostFoot'
},

handleGhostHead: function () {},
handleGhostFoot: function () {},

install: function () {

},

uninstall: function () {

},

//Register Handlebars Helpers on activate
activate: function (posts) {
    //Test for getting post content
    this.ghost.api.posts.read(0).then(function (post) {
        console.log(post.title);
        return post.title
    });
    this.ghost.helpers.register('content_block', this.content_block_helper);
    this.ghost.helpers.register('if_eq', this.if_eq);
},

deactivate: function () {

},

content_block_helper: function(node, posts) {
    var content = post.data.root.post.html;
    var regexstring = '<content_block'+ node +'>[\\s\\S]*?<\/content_block'+ 
node + '>'
    var regexp = new RegExp(regexstring);
    if(content.match(regexp)){
      var match = content.match(regexp)
      match = match.replace('<content_block'+ node + '>', '');
      match = match.replace('</content_block'+ node + '>', '');
      return new hbs.SafeString(match)
    } else {
       return('My first Handlebars Helper');
    }

},

if_eq: function(a, b, opts) {
    if (a == b) {
      return opts.fn(this);
    } else {
      return opts.inverse(this);
    }
}

});

module.exports = helpers_briefcase;
```

Thanks in advance.

Disclaimer: I consider myself something between a dedicated hobbyist and an expert, so before you go pointing out what javascript sins I've committed, please keep this in mind (go easy with pointing out errors outside of the problem I'm trying to solve) *thanks S.O Community.

Comment: Working on a similar problem, did you ever end up solving this one?  I will post back if I find a solution.

Comment: Unfortunately I abandoned that path due to time constraints. I'm working on a new theme for ghost this year and would love to give it another shot. If you find a solution that would be awesome. I'll do the same if I do too. A lot has also changed since I posted this. I'm cosidering going headless with ghost for this next project. Ill let you know how it goes

Comment: Ended up moving the entire frontend over to Vue and accessing ghost via the content api. Way more flexibility and totally circumvents the need to go this route.